# Realm .Net Core2 String.Contains() fails?

Tags: uwp, realm, .net-core-2.0

Using the Realm database for a UWP app.   We're upgrading from .NETCore 1.4 to NETCore 2.0, and the Realm String.Contains() function broke.

The query in question is as follows:

```
var collections = realm.All<Collection>().Where(c =>
    c.Title.Contains(query, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
    c.TextDescription.Contains(query, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

When attempting to use results from that query (eg: `collections.ToList()`), we get the following exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in 
System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
The method 'Contains' is not supported
```

Is this not supported in Core 2?

Comment: `String.Contains()` method should work in UWP. What're your OS build version and project target version? What's the version of 'Realm'?

Comment: String.Contains() does work in UWP.   It doesn't work as part of a Realm query / filter.


While the above doesn't work, iterating through the collection and checking each for the query string does work.

OS Version: 1803   (17134.407)

Target version: 1803 (17134)

Min version: Fall Creators Update (16299)

Realm version: 3.3.0

Comment: If so, you could report this issue on [Realm GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues).

Comment: Yea, they recommended to post here first, so was trying that, but if no response I'll try there